# find min values excluding zero by each element index in a list of objects

Tags: python

I have this function below which makes object instances as list,

```
lst = []

class Ppl:
    def __init__(self, pid):
        # local variables
        self.pid = pid
        self.pos = [3*pid, 10+pid-4*pid, 5*pid] 

for index in range(3):        
    lst.append(Ppl(index))

for index in range(len(lst)):
    print(lst[index].pos)
```

The above will output.

```
[0, 10, 0]
[3, 7, 5]
[6, 4, 10]
```

now I want to make a comprehension list based on the above lists to get the minimum values excluding zero.. so that the **expected output** is

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

I have this function below which works but it includes 0.

```
lst2 = list(map(min, *[x.pos for x in lst]))

print(lst2)
>> [0, 4, 0]
```

So is there a way to improve the above code or is there a better solution ?

Comment: I don't quite follow your requirements here. When you say "exactly what I want", that doesn't seem to match your description, because `3` is the smallest element above zero but it's not included in your output. Are you picking the 3 minimum elements across all lists? I ask because I notice `Ppl[0]` has no number in the list.

Comment: ggorlen, I meant it works as I want only problem being it includes 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are restricted to use one-liner, here is possible solution:

```
lst2 = list(map(lambda *args: min(arg for arg in args if arg != 0), *[x.pos for x in lst]))
```

`min` replaced with a lambda that applies `min` after filtering zero values.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily define yourself a function for this:

```
def min2(iterator, threshold = 0):
    minvalue = None
    for x in iterator:
        if (x > threshold) and (x < minvalue or minvalue is None):
            minvalue = x

    return minvalue
```

Test it with some asserts:

```
assert min2([0, 10, 0]) == 10
assert min2([3, 7, 5]) == 3
assert min2([6, 4, 10]) == 4
assert min2([10, 10, 101], threshold=100) == 101
```

Comment: Not a bad approach but im being restricted to use one line / inline function.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code snippet.

```
import numpy as np
lst2 = np.array([x.pos for x in lst])
lst2[lst2==0]=np.max(lst2)
print(np.min(lst2,axis=0))
```

Output:
[3 4 5]